# How do I insert onsubmit in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to insert some form values into a db table , how would I create a function to call once the user clicks on the button and run the insert scrtipt .

```
<form name="quiz_info" method="post">

<?php 
echo $this->quiz->title;

echo $mainframe->getPageTitle();

echo '<p><input type="checkbox" id="checkToProceed" name="checkToProceed" onclick="proceed();" />

<label for="checkToProceed">' . JText::_('I have Read and Acknowledge the procedure'). '</label></p>' ;

echo '<input id="proceedButton" name="proceedButton" disabled="true" value="' . JText::_('Acknowledge') . '" type="submit" />' ;



//Declare Variables

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');
$name = $user->get('name');
$username = $user->get('username');
$department = $user->get('department');
$vardate = date("m/d/y : H:i:s", time());        
$courseTitle = $mainframe->getPageTitle();

$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

$query ="INSERT INTO `jos_jquarks_users_acknowledge` (course_name,user_id,employeeNumber,department,name,acknoledge,timeStamp) VALUES ($courseTitle,$id,$username,$department,$name,acknoledge,vardate)";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();

?>

<input type="hidden" name="layout" value="default" />
<?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?> 
</form>
```

Comment: `<form onsubmit="return yourfunction()">` It's enough? As I can see, you're misunderstanding the way PHP works. As Zeta said, it's server-side language and stateless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['proceedButton'] != '') {
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $id = $user->get('id');
        $name = $user->get('name');
        $username = $user->get('username');
        $department = $user->get('department');
        $vardate = date("m/d/y : H:i:s", time());        
        $courseTitle = $mainframe->getPageTitle();

        $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
        $query ="INSERT INTO `jos_jquarks_users_acknowledge`(course_name,user_id,employeeNumber,department,name,acknoledge,timeStamp) VALUES ($courseTitle,$id,$username,$department,$name,acknoledge,vardate)";
        $db->setQuery( $query );
        $db->query();
    }
?>

<form name="quiz_info" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <?php echo $this->quiz->title; ?>
    <?php echo $mainframe->getPageTitle(); ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkToProceed" name="checkToProceed" onclick="proceed();" />
    <label for="checkToProceed"><?php echo JText::_('I have Read and Acknowledge the procedure'); ?></label>
    <input id="proceedButton" name="proceedButton" disabled="true" value="<?php JText::_('Acknowledge'); ?>" type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="layout" value="default" />
    <?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?> 
</form>
```

Comment: Will fail. `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` evaluates to null.

Comment: Hi, the curly brace `}` after the `$db->query();` is the equivalent of `end if`.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is executed on the server-side. If you want to call the function without reloading the page you will have to use an AJAX call, for example with jQuery.

You can find billions of tutorials through google.

Comment: Yes, and this site should be one of them :) [See Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: I agree completely with the link. My motivation for not going into details is that I wasn't sure that this was the answer the poster was looking for. I didn't want to spend that much time writing an answer on (for a beginner) not so obvious technique which others have written much better about.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work this way. If you wish to activate your PHP script on form submit, you'll need to **submit the form to a PHP page**, and ***on that page*** to put your script, for example

```
<form action=submit.php method=post>

    <input type=text name=text>
    <input type=submit>

</form>
```

Next, on **submit.php**:

```
<?php

    if (!empty($_POST['text'])) { //If the POST variable set by input named 'text' is not empty...
        echo $_POST['text']; //Print it on the screen.
    } else { //If it is empty
        echo "No form submission detected"; //Print an error
    }

?>
```

If you want it to work without a page reload, you'll have to use some client side technology. The most popular one for that purpose is **[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax)**